# Laravel 8: Syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

im doing the Laravel 8 from Scratch Tutorial but get the Error "Syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)".
Cant find where the problem is because there is not even a "@if" statement in the file which is throwing the error.
The file is the header for filtering posts.
It seems the dropdown component which is responsible for selecting a post category is the reason for the problem, because everything workes fine when i comment this out.

**I have shared the Error Code on [flareapp.io](https://flareapp.io/share/NPLkwe8m#F63)**

Dropdown Component:

```html
@props(['trigger'])

<div x-data="{ show:false }" @click.away="show = false">
    <div @click="show = ! show">
        {{ $trigger }}
    </div>

    <div x-show="show" class="py-2 absolute bg-gray-100 mt-2 rounded-xl w-32 z-50" style="display: none">
        {{ $slot }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Dropdown-item Component:

```html
@props(['active' => false])

@php
$classes = 'block text-left px-3 text-sm loading-6 hover:bg-blue-500 focues:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white focus:text-white';

if ($active) {
    $classes += 'bg-blue-500 text-white';
}
    
@endphp

<a {{ $attributes(['class' => $classes]) }}>
    {{ $slot }}
</a>
```

Posts header:

```html
<header class="max-w-xl mx-auto mt-20 text-center">
    <h1 class="text-4xl">
        Latest <span class="text-blue-500">Laravel From Scratch</span> News
    </h1>

    <h2 class="inline-flex mt-2">By Lary Laracore <img src="./images/lary-head.svg" alt="Head of Lary the mascot"></h2>

    <p class="text-sm mt-14">
        Another year. Another update. We're refreshing the popular Laravel series with new content.
        I'm going to keep you guys up to speed with what's going on!
    </p>

    <div class="space-y-2 lg:space-y-0 lg:space-x-4 mt-8">
        <!--  Category -->
        <div class="relative lg:inline-flex bg-gray-100 rounded-xl">

            <x-dropdown>
                <x-slot name="trigger">
                    <button class="py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-sm font-semibold w-full lg:w-32 text-left flex lg:inline-flex">

                        {{ isset($currentCategory) ? ucwords($currentCategory->name) : 'Categories' }}

                        <svg class="transform -rotate-90 absolute pointer-events-none" style="right: 12px;" width="22"
                            height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
                            <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                <path stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".012" stroke-width=".5" d="M21 1v20.16H.84V1z">
                                </path>
                                <path fill="#222"
                                    d="M13.854 7.224l-3.847 3.856 3.847 3.856-1.184 1.184-5.04-5.04 5.04-5.04z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </x-slot>

                <x-dropdown-item href="/blog/" :active="request()->routeIs(" none")">
                    All
                </x-dropdown-item>

                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                    <x-dropdown-item href="/blog/categories/{{ $category->slug }}" :active="request()->is("
                        categories/{$category->slug}")"
                        >
                        {{ ucwords($category->name) }}
                    </x-dropdown-item>
                @endforeach
            </x-dropdown>

        </div>

        <!-- Other Filters -->
        <div class="relative flex lg:inline-flex items-center bg-gray-100 rounded-xl">
            <select class="flex-1 appearance-none bg-transparent py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-sm font-semibold">
                <option value="category" disabled selected>Other Filters
                </option>
                <option value="foo">Foo
                </option>
                <option value="bar">Bar
                </option>
            </select>

            {{-- ERROR THROWN IN NEXT LINE --}}
            <svg class="transform -rotate-90 absolute pointer-events-none" style="right: 12px;" width="22" height="22"
                viewBox="0 0 22 22">
                <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                    <path stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".012" stroke-width=".5" d="M21 1v20.16H.84V1z">
                    </path>
                    <path fill="#222" d="M13.854 7.224l-3.847 3.856 3.847 3.856-1.184 1.184-5.04-5.04 5.04-5.04z">
                    </path>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>

        <!-- Search -->
        <div class="relative flex lg:inline-flex items-center bg-gray-100 rounded-xl px-3 py-2">
            <form method="GET" action="#">
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Find something"
                    class="bg-transparent placeholder-black font-semibold text-sm">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    <x-dropdown-item href="/blog/categories/{{ $category->slug }}" :active="request()->is('categories/' . $category->slug)">
        {{ ucwords($category->name) }}
    </x-dropdown-item>
@endforeach
```

Comment: No this didnt solved the problem. Same error code.

Comment: Can try update this `:active="request()->routeIs(" none")"` to this `:active="request()->routeIs('none')"`